# Approximation of a Riemann sum (not really) by a Laplacian integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request, riemann-sum, laplace-method

I have a sum of the form:

$$S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm{e}^{n f(i/n)} g(i/n)$$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are smooth functions defined for $0\le x \le 1$. I am interested in the Asymptotic behaviour of $S_n$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

What I have tried is to replace the sum by an integral:

$$S_n \approx\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{n f(x)} g(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

and then I was thinking of doing a saddle-point approximation ([Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#cite_ref-2)), but I am not sure of the validity of replacing the sum by the integral. It looks like a Riemann sum, except for the $n$ multiplying $f$ in the exponent.

Any suggestions appreciated.

If it makes your life easier assume that $f(x)$ has a single maximum inside the interval $x\in(0,1)$.

I'd be happy if someone could at least point out some reference to the literature where sums like this have popped out before. I have the feeling that this has been treated before.

**Edit, TLTR.** The summarized version of the question is: Prove or disprove that $S_n / I_n \rightarrow c$ for some constant $c$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where

$$S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm{e}^{n f(i/n)} g(i/n), \quad I_n = \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{n f(x)} g(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Moreover, is the difference between $I_n$ and $S_n$ exponentially decreasing in $n$? That is, $|I_nc - S_n| / S_n = \mathcal{O}(n^p e^{-qn})$ for some numbers $p,q$?

Comment: It's not a Riemann sum, but the replacement could be justified, nonetheless. To prove that under such weak assumptions is another question, though. And it depends on what you mean by $\approx$. If it's an $O(...)$ in an _exponent_, it might work.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I am not sure what I mean by $\approx$ yet, I have to find out. Right now I want to know how close is the sum to the integral. Maybe their ratio goes to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? Or their absolute difference goes to zero? ... I do not know yet! That is the question.

Comment: But there should be something similar to this out there ... Has anyone ever considered integrations / sums like these? I must be missing a keyword.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Maybe you can expand on your comment? What do you mean by "if it's an $O(...)$ in an exponent..."?

Comment: I think about Borel summation !!!!!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Can you expand?